# Infinitesimal volume using differentials

Tags: calculus

I don't understand why in some texts they put that infinitesimal volume $dV = dx dy dz$. If $ V = V(x,y, z)$ infinitesimal volume should be $$dV = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} dx +\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}  dy + \frac{\partial V}{\partial z} dz$$

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: May be, but I posted it here because modern mathematicians almost wiped out the concept of infinitesimal from calculus, although still it is stillwidely used in sciences, like physics. (See http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/bridge/papers/differentials.pdf) So, I thought physicists could better explain me that.

Comment: Actually, it's been proved that infinitesimals don't lead to any problems after all. For a discussion at an elementary level, see http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html .

Comment: If $V$ is a function, writing $\mathrm dV$ for the volume element is just a bad thing to do. I'd write $\mathrm d^3x$ or $\omega_V$, depending on who's gonna read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume of a finite box is $\Delta x \Delta y \Delta z$. The infinitesimals are simply thought of as very small deltas -- so small that they're smaller than any real number. (This can be formalized in terms of [non-standard analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis).)

What may have misled you was the notation $dV$. This simply means an infinitesimally small volume. It doesn't mean that $V$ is a function being differentiated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two independent concepts here.

1. One is that of an **infinitesimal volume**, also referred to as a [differential volume element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element). $$dV = dxdydz$$
   This represents a small volume that you would use to derive conservation equations for example. See also [infinitesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) for a more general definition.

2 .The second is a concept of a [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function), $$dV = \frac{\partial V }{\partial x } dx+ \frac{\partial V }{\partial y }dy+ \frac{\partial V }{\partial z }dz$$

This  differential represents a change in the linearization of a function.